# AngularJS set active attribute

Tags: angularjs

I have a tabset and I can set one tab active with the active attribute.
Is there a directive where I can set the active flag, e.g. like ng-active or something like that.

```
<tabset>
    <tab active="true"> 
        /* content */
    </tab>
    <tab>   
        /* content */
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind active property of tab to some angularJS variable:

```
<tab active="activeFlag">
```

after that set activeFlag from angular controller:

```
$scope.activeFlag = true;
```